# What is the absolute path to the file that contains all the drives?

Tags: boot, paths

What is the absolute path to the file that contains all the drives, hardware and network shares, that are mounted by the system during boot?

Comment: I've flagged your question to close because it is not specific enough. Please explain more what kind of problem you try to solve.

Answer (score 4):

That is `/etc/fstab` (for its syntax see `man fstab`).

To be more precise it doesn't contain drives but filesystems to be mounted.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single file that contains ***all*** drives, shares, etc. to be mounted at startup. `/etc/fstab` is where you're supposed to add these, but in practice, any method for [running a command on startup](https://askubuntu.com/q/814/158442) as root can be used for mounting.

In the systemd world, the canonical way to mount anything at boot would be using [systemd mounts](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html). In systemd, even entries in `fstab` are converted to `.mount`s by the [`systemd-fstab-generator`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fstab-generator.html).

```
~ systemctl list-units --type=mount
UNIT                          LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION                                  
-.mount                       loaded active mounted Root Mount                                   
boot.mount                    loaded active mounted /boot                                        
dev-hugepages.mount           loaded active mounted Huge Pages File System                       
dev-mqueue.mount              loaded active mounted POSIX Message Queue File System     
...

~ systemctl cat -- -.mount                    
# /run/systemd/generator/-.mount
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
Before=local-fs.target

[Mount]
Where=/
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/e5018f7e-5838-4a47-b146-fc1614673356
Type=ext4
Options=rw,relatime,data=ordered
```